# How to handle Multiple MySQL Tables using DataImportHandler in Solr?

Tags: mysql, indexing, solr

Below mentioned query works perfectly fine while running it on phpmyadmin. I want to index these tables completely using solr and generate aggregated result using single query.

```
"select biblio.biblionumber as 'id', biblio.*, biblioitems.*, items.*, branches.* from biblio
inner join biblioitems ON (biblioitems.biblionumber=biblio.biblionumber)
inner join items ON (items.biblionumber=biblio.biblionumber)
inner join branches ON (branches.uid=items.uid);
```

I gave it a try on solr but could not get the desired result using this :

```
<document>
<entity name="id" query="select biblio.biblionumber as 'id', biblio.* from biblio ;">
            <field column="BIBLIONUMBER" name="biblionumber" />
            <field column="AUTHOR" name="author" />
            <field column="TITLE" name="title" />
                <field column="SERIESTITLE" name="seriestitle" />
            <field column="COPYRIGHTDATE" name="copyrightdate" />
            <field column="ABSTRACT" name="abstract" />

            <entity name="id2" query="select biblioitems.biblioitemnumber as 'id2', biblioitems.* from biblioitems where biblionumber='${biblio.id}'">
                <field name="BIBLIOITEMNUMBER" column="biblioitemnumber" />
                <field name="ISBN" column="isbn" />
                <field name="ISSN" column="issn" />
                <field name="PUBLISHERCODE" column="publishercode" />
                <field name="EDITIONSTATEMENT" column="editionstatement" />
                <field name="PAGES" column="pages" />
                <field name="PLACE" column="place" />
                <field name="URL" column="url" />
            </entity>
            <entity name="id3" query="select items.uid as 'id3', items.* from items where biblionumber='${biblio.id}'">
                    <field  name="ITEMNUMBER" column="itemnumber" />
                    <field  name="PRICE" column="price" />
                    <field  name="BARCODE" column="barcode" />
                    <field  name="ENUMCHRON" column="enumchron" />
                    <field  name="UID" column="uid" />
                    <field  name="HOMEBRANCH" column="homebranch" />

                <entity name="id4" query="select branches.uid AS 'id4', branches.* from branches where uid = '${items.id3}'">
                    <field  name="UID" column="uid" />
                    <field  name="BRANCHNAME" column="branchname" />
                </entity>
            </entity>
        </entity>
</document>
```

The result is displayed upto abstract the moment join operation comes into play. I'm struggling with the query.

I request you all to help me with this query.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: cant you write in a single query ?

Comment: Could you please show the results you have before join and after?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use your original query to get the data you want into Solr?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti 

**select biblio.biblionumber as 'id', biblio.*, biblioitems.*, items.*, branches.* from biblio
inner join biblioitems ON (biblioitems.biblionumber=biblio.biblionumber)
inner join items ON (items.biblionumber=biblio.biblionumber)
inner join branches ON (branches.uid=items.uid);**


This is one single query

Comment: @MatsLindh if write this original query in my db-data-config.xml . Solr does not fetch any data from mysql to index and as per my findings on web if I want to work with joins solr recommends DIH queries.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your concern, I've figured out the problem in above query. **Entity name should be your table name.**